# Python regex is having problems finding a special unicode character

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am currently parsing through some old exams to determine the frequency of the questions (because many questions would resurface at this years exam). I am using pyperclip to get the input for the re.findall.

This is the regex I am using: `pattern = re.compile(ur'\d.[a-zA-Z .,\']+\?', re.UNICODE)`, and this is an example question on an older exam (the pattern I am trying to find): `9. In Wycherley’s The Country Wife, what does Mr. Pinchwife threaten to inscribe on Mrs. Pinchwife’s face with his penknife?` The apostrophe is not one I can find on my keyboard, and trying to execute the code results in this error:

```
 File "examAnalyzer.py", line 7
    pattern = re.compile(ur'\d.[a-zA-Z .,\Æ]+\?', re.UNICODE)
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am using Python 2.7.11 and Anaconda 4.0, and the Python file is edited using VIM.

Comment: Can't you use `\u2019`? BTW, the `.` should be escaped when you need to match a literal dot. Try `ur'\d\.[a-zA-Z .,\'\u2019]+\?'`

Comment: Would you look at that, it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\u` representation of the apostrophe, which is `\u2019`.

Also, the dot should be escaped to match a literal dot symbol.

Use

```
ur'\d\.[a-zA-Z .,\'\u2019]+\?'
     ^^            ^^^^^^
```

When in doubt what the hex representation a symbol has, you can check it at [*r12a >> apps >> Unicode code converter*](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Answer (score 0):

Your python file has declared a file encoding of utf8 but the file itself is saved in another encoding.

You should give the correct encoding in the first line:

```
# -*- coding: <correct encoding> -*-
```

Comment: Which encoding is the correct? I have declared utf-8 as encoding in this script.

Comment: @gloriousCatnip: If you want to include Unicode literal characters in your script I recommend you use UTF-8. Use a valid UTF-8 `# -*- coding:` directive at the top of your script so the Python interpreter knows what encoding has been used (there are several valid forms, see [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263)), and you also need to tell your editor / IDE to use UTF-8.